# Ajax Call is failed - NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax

In my web application i have implemented an ajax call to fetch a json data from server side implementation(java).

The ajax call is mentioned below :

**Ajax Call A**

```
$.ajax({                            
    url : "/example/getStudentData?param=Y",
    dataType : "json",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success : function(data) {
        responseStudentData = data;
    }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("Fail Ajax call and error - "+errorThrown);
    });
```

**Ajax Call B**

```
$.ajax({                            
    url : "/example/getEmployeeData?searchFields=empCode&resultFields=empCode~stuName",
    dataType : "json",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success : function(data) {
      responseEmployeeData = data;
    }
});
```

I have also a login mechanism in my web application and the above ajax calls is fired when user logged into the application.

When user logged into the application, the above mentioned ajax calls is working fine and it is giving me the expected response.

Once the user logged into the application and refresh the page or clicks on a link (let say 'details') - both ajax calls get fired again.

In this case **ajax call B** is working fine but **ajax call A** failed and it is giving the following error in console :

> https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=http-3A__exampletest.esl.local_example_getStudentData-3Fparam-3DY-26fr-5F-3Dapp-26-5F-3D1568216981427&d=DwIGAg&c=CpmKhcvZpeBSDb9wW5aqSg&r=mZ9q9fk06ajG-9qtccmI_MxzR-gE0l-bNkgS7mv6Z2A&m=eC4WhKr8SjcQOM_-BaSyu-JkIPFhE3_azQ3qlxsPvUw&s=dMsefmbwn5yPmip1Cf7mbGUAkcwtkFlmYym2A4cAa0E&e=
>   **net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

and when the fail section of the same ajax call(ajax call A) is executed, the below error is displayed :

Fail Ajax call and error:

> NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to
>   load**
>
> 'https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=http-3A__exampletest.esl.local_example_getStudentData-3Fparam-3DY-26fr-5F-3Dapp-26-5F-3D1568216981427&d=DwIGAg&c=CpmKhcvZpeBSDb9wW5aqSg&r=mZ9q9fk06ajG-9qtccmI_MxzR-gE0l-bNkgS7mv6Z2A&m=eC4WhKr8SjcQOM_-BaSyu-JkIPFhE3_azQ3qlxsPvUw&s=dMsefmbwn5yPmip1Cf7mbGUAkcwtkFlmYym2A4cAa0E&e=
>   '.

The issue is only with ajax call A and it is failed everytime except login.

The issue is only replicable only at client production server.

Please suggest me the exact cause of this problem and appropriate solution for the same.

Comment: https://www.proofpoint.com/au/resources/data-sheets/essentials-url-defense

Comment: @Phil...i have already gone though the data sheet provided by proofpoint. But this is not helpful for me.